# How do I make a more specific url for location.href.match?

Tags: javascript

I am using a series of if statements to manipulate css on a forum using the following:

```
if(location.href.match(/(showforum=3)/i) != null) {
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#topimg").addClass("announce");
});}
```

The code works perfectly fine, but every other showforum beginning with a 3 displays this image unless I  code it otherwise. So my question would be how do I make my location more exact so that it only makes changes to 3 and not 3x? Is it even possible using this coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex so that the "value's boundary" is checked as well:

```
var pattern = /showforum=3(?=&|$)/i;
if (pattern.test(location.href)) {
  ...
}
```

Note the accompanying change in the testing expression: if you only need to find out whether or not some string matches the pattern, you should use `regexp.test(string)` syntax, not `string.match(regexp) !== null`.

Comment: I was hoping to squeak by simply with loads of shortcuts, but I suppose I'll have to man up and L2Syntax properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

if( getParameterByName("showforum") == 3 ){
    //........

}
```

Ref

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)